# module ‘lstm’ has no attribute ‘load_data’

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

I am trying to implement a LSTM neural network in python.

My code looks like:

```
import pandas
# with date as dataframe index
df_daily = pandas.read_csv('daily_data.csv', index_col='Date')
df_daily = df_daily.drop(['MinMax Price (input 2)'], axis =1)

from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
import lstm, time #libraries to assist

x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = lstm.load_data(df_daily, 50, True)
x_train.head(5)
```

however when running:

> x_training, y_training, x_test, y_test = lstm.load_data(df_daily, 50,
>   True)

I get the error:

> module ‘lstm’ has no attribute ‘load_data’

I really don't understand why I'm getting this error. I have also tried installing "theano-lstm" and "theano".

Kindly assist please.

Comment: lstm is not a well known python module, so what is is and why do you think it has a load_data method?

Comment: I actually think it doesn't have a load method but I have seen multiple cases of the load method working but it doesn't seem to work in my case. So I'm just confused now.

Comment: Sure but those are in different modules, you can't call random functions in random modules and ask why it doesn't work :) In this case you just need to format the data from your dataframe.